# Kafka Custom Deserializer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So far, I've been able to create a KStream with the help of a topic.

```
KStream<String, Object> testqa2 = builder.stream("testqa2", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .mapValues(value -> {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    return value;
                });
```

It doesn't print anything, so on debbuging - I realized I am just creating my KStream. There is no data in it.

I am having a litte trouble creating serializer/deserializer for worker class.

```
package com.copart.mwa.Avro;

public class Worker {

    private static String WorkerActivityName;
    private static String WorkerSid;
    private static String WorkerPreviousActivityName;
    private static String WorkerPreviousActivitySid;

    public String getWorkerActivityName() {
        return WorkerActivityName;
    }

    public void setWorkerActivityName(String workerActivityName) {
        WorkerActivityName = workerActivityName;
    }

    public static String getWorkerSid() {
        return WorkerSid;
    }

    public void setWorkerSid(String workerSid) {
        WorkerSid = workerSid;
    }

    public String getWorkerPreviousActivityName() {
        return WorkerPreviousActivityName;
    }

    public void setWorkerPreviousActivityName(String workerPreviousActivityName) {
        WorkerPreviousActivityName = workerPreviousActivityName;
    }

    public String getWorkerPreviousActivitySid() {
        return WorkerPreviousActivitySid;
    }

    public void setWorkerPreviousActivitySid(String workerPreviousActivitySid) {
        WorkerPreviousActivitySid = workerPreviousActivitySid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Worker(" + WorkerSid + ", " + WorkerActivityName + ")";
    } }
```

And the message from the producer to the consumer is a JSON

```
  {
"WorkerActivityName": "Available",
"EventType": "worker.activity.update",
"ResourceType": "worker",
"WorkerTimeInPreviousActivityMs": "237",
"Timestamp": "1626114642",
"WorkerActivitySid": "WAc9030ef021bc1786d3ae11544f4d9883",
"WorkerPreviousActivitySid": "WAf4feb231e97c1878fecc58b26fdb95f3",
"WorkerTimeInPreviousActivity": "0",
"AccountSid": "AC8c5cd8c9ba538090da104b26d68a12ec",
"WorkerName": "Dorothy.Finegan@Copart.Com",
"Sid": "EV284c8a8bc27480e40865263f0b42e5cf",
"TimestampMs": "1626114642204",
"P": "WKe638256376188fab2a98cccb3c803d67",
"WorkspaceSid": "WS38b10d521442ecb74fcc263d5a4d726e",
"WorkspaceName": "Copart-MiPhone",
"WorkerPreviousActivityName": "Unavailable(RNA)",
"EventDescription": "Worker Dorothy.Finegan@Copart.Com updated to Available Activity",
"ResourceSid": "WKe638256376188fab2a98cccb3c803d67",
"WorkerAttributes": "{\"miphone_dept\":[\"USA_YRD_OPS\"],\"languages\":[\"en\"],\"home_region\":\"GL\",\"roles\":[\"supervisor\"],\"miphone_yards\":[\"81\"],\"miphone_enabled\":true,\"miphone_states\":[\"IL\"],\"home_state\":\"IL\",\"skills\":[\"YD_SELLER\",\"YD_TITLE\"],\"home_division\":\"Northern\",\"miphone_divisions\":[\"Northern\"],\"miphone_functions\":[\"outbound_only\"],\"full_name\":\"Dorothy Finegan\",\"miphone_regions\":[\"GL\"],\"home_country\":\"USA\",\"copart_user_id\":\"USA3204\",\"home_yard\":\"81\",\"home_dept\":\"USA_YRD_OPS\",\"email\":\"dorothy.finegan@copart.com\",\"home_dept_category\":\"OPS\",\"contact_uri\":\"client:Dorothy_2EFinegan_40Copart_2ECom\",\"queue_activity\":\"Available\",\"teams\":[],\"remote_employee\":false,\"miphone_call_center_units\":[\"USA_YRD_OPS|81\"],\"miphone_call_center_teams\":[]}"
}
```

I want to implemenet a customer deserializer where

"WorkspaceSid": "**WS38b10d521442ecb74fcc263d5a4d726e**", is the key and the remaining values of the other attributes act as the value for the key-value pair.

Thanks,
Anmol

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't print anything

If there is data in `testqa2` topic, and you have `auto.offset.reset=earliest`, then it should.

> having a litte trouble creating serializer/deserializer for worker class

Kafka has bulit-in JSON serializers that you can build a Serde for. You don't need to make your own.

> "WorkspaceSid", is the key

use `selectKey`, or `map` if you want to modify the key, not `mapValues`

```
Serializer<JsonNode> jsonNodeSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonNodeDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
final Serde<JsonNode> jsonNodeSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonNodeSerializer,jsonNodeDeserializer);

KStream<String, JsonNode> testqa2 = builder.stream("testqa2", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
    .selectKey((k, json) -> json.get("WorkspaceSid"))
    .print(Printed.toSysOut());
```

Alternatively, fix your producer code to get the `Sid` from the value, and set the key there...

If you want to use Avro, you wouldn't write a Worker class - you would generate it from an Avro schema.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But my main goal is to create a Ktable out of testqa2 topic.

Comment: Okay... That wasn't part of your question, though. As I told you before, use `groupByKey` and `aggregate` to get a KTable

Comment: The issues with the aggregate is:


My data (payload) is in string/json


{
"WorkerActivityName": "Available",
"EventType": "worker.activity.update",
"ResourceType": "worker",
"WorkerTimeInPreviousActivityMs": "237",
"Timestamp": "1626114642",
"WorkerActivitySid": "WAc9030ef021bc1786d3ae11544f4d9883",
"WorkerPreviousActivitySid": "WAf4feb231e97c1878fecc58b26fdb95f3",
"WorkerTimeInPreviousActivity": "0",
}

Now I want to print all data, where worker activity name is available. PK = W activity sid

How to form the ktable from this?

Comment: @anmol I assume you have completely followed the [tutorial](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/join-a-stream-to-a-table/kstreams.html) I linked to before? And I believe I answered the original question you asked, so if you have a specific error on creating a Table, I suggest creating a new post (or editing one of your previous ones)

Comment: Yes, i have understood the tutorial. I have one doubt tho. If you create a Ktable from builder.table(topic) how do you access it's data? If it's interactive queries, in my use case, can u help build it? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Did you look at the [Interactive Queries examples](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/code-examples.html#interactive-queries-examples)?

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/6.2.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java

In this they're creating an aggregation from two topics. I have one topic to build my table.

Comment: Then dont use that one, use the other https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/6.2.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/WordCountInteractiveQueriesExample.java#L220

Comment: Otherwise, look at `songPlays.groupBy(...).count()`, which returns a table, and `count()` is just a specific type of `aggregate`